# Is there a benefit to avoiding extra class instantiations?

Tags: php, refactoring, dry

Below is some code that uses Zend Form API to create a form and to create subforms (aka Fieldsets)

The `AnnotationBuilder` class does not appear to have a `__construct` associated with it, so instantiating a new `AnnotationBuilder` object is a light-weight operation.

That said, I believe it okay to leave the code below as is:

```
$form = (new AnnotationBuilder())->createForm(CustomForm::class);
$form->add((new AnnotationBuilder())->createForm(CustomFieldset1::class));
$form->add((new AnnotationBuilder())->createForm(CustomFieldset2::class));
```

Is there any need to refactor the above code or is it safe to leave it as is?  Performance-wise I do not believe there is any significant penalty except a couple of extra object instantiations.

As an alternative, for example, I was considering creating a variable to hold a `new AnnotationBuilder()`, either as the local or at the class-scope, and then reusing that variable as needed.  But I don't necessarily see a benefit of doing that here.

Comment: `new AnnotationBuilder()` _constructs_ a new object. That uses memory - it's irrelevant _how_ much. If you're keen on (micro)optimizations, you want to avoid that. Unless _it's required_ to build a new object.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a reason why you should **NOT** use `$builder = new AnnotationBuilder();`.

You just would waste microseconds by instantiating the builder. Probably the `AnnotationBuilder` has some internal logic which provides performance optimizations on some elements within your form, e.g. by using some kind of property cache, e.g.

I would not recommend to create any object again and again until you really want to get a fresh one.